# Changing font for a specific symbol in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I intended to use a specific font with ggplot, which I've been able to achieve with the `showtext` package since I could only find the font in .otf format.

However, I realised the new font does not include the euro symbol (€). Therefore, when I change the font in ggplot, I get a blank space instead of the symbol.

```
library(tidyverse)

library(showtext)
font_add("Gulliver", ".../Windows/Fonts/Gulliver Regular.otf")
showtext_auto()

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Gulliver")) +
  labs(y = bquote("mpg - (€ & " ~m^2 ~")"),
       x = "€€€")
```

The following code is the one causing blank spaces (left), if I remove the `theme(text = element_text(family = "Gulliver")) +` line, though, all euro symbols appear with no problem (right).

[image]
[image]

I was considering to change somehow the font used solely on the € symbol to the default one and having all the other text in the font I selected. Is there a way to achieve it or an easier path to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is an easier option to get the euro symbol for the font you are using, but if you want to go the route with using different font families then you could achieve your desired result using `ggtext` which allows to style text using some limited amount of HTML and CSS and is sufficient to add a superscript. To this end we have to use `ggtext::element_markdown` instead of `element_text`.

In the reprex I have set the font family for `text` elements to `times` but use `sans` for the euro symbol.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

mtcars |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  theme(text = element_text(
    family = "times"
  ),
  axis.title.y = element_markdown()
  ) +
  labs(
    y = "mpg - (<span style='font-family: sans'>€</span> & m<sup>2</sup>)",
    x = "€€€"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Would this solution still work for a secondary axis ```scale_y_continuos(sec.axis =...)```?

Comment: In general yes. But you probably have to be a more specific in the theme, i.e. use `axis.title.y.right=`.